# Throttle a button click with a function that requires a parameter that is a button attribute - Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, closures, addeventlistener, throttling

struggling to wrap my head around this one. I've just delved into the world of throttling, closures and avoiding global variables.

I have multiple buttons:

```
<a content_name="home" class="menuLink"><span>HOME</span></a>
```

I would like to throttle clicks on each of these buttons until getContent is done (for the sake of the question let's assume it will take 200ms).

My javascript:

```
function getContent(contentName) {
   //Does some things
}

// Simply throttle function

function throttle(callback, limit) {
    var throttleLock = false;
    console.log('throttling: ' + throttleLock);
    return function () {                
        if (!throttleLock) {            
            callback.call();            
            throttleLock = true;        
            setTimeout(function () {    
                throttleLock = false;   
            }, limit);
        }
    }
};

// Event listeners for the buttons

var menuButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("menuLink"); 

var menuBtnClick = function() {
    var attribute = this.getAttribute('content_name');
    getContent(attribute);
};

for (var i = 0; i < menuButtons.length; i++) {
    menuButtons[i].addEventListener('click', throttle(menuBtnClick, 500), false);
}
```

If I refactor as this (without the throttle function) everything works fine, except that it doesn't throttle (obviously):

```
for (var i = 0; i < menuButtons.length; i++) {
    menuButtons[i].addEventListener('click', menuBtnClick, 200), false);
}
```

The log error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function
    at menuBtnClick ([this is my filename and line])
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> ([this is my filename and line])
```

I know that the throttle function is firing ( console log ), but it doesn't seem to fire the callback and the value of throttleLock remains false.

Please help, I'm sure I've done something wrong and I want to learn. If there are any alternatives to this attempt please fire away I'm all ears.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply context to callback call:

```
callback.call(this);
```

Here is the example:
https://jsbin.com/yekimaqelo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Wow, just like that... Thanks so much! I don't want to hassle but could you maybe go a lil more in-depth, I can't quite get why it works? Thanks.